# Sum duplicate values in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am storing category and amount values to core data.I want to display the top 5 categories to the User.I am able to get the results but how to sum the amount for similar categories and display the top 5.?

I have tried some logic for summing up the amount for the category but I am stuck there and I also want to know whether I am doing it right or not.

```
  NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
for(int i = 0; i < [results count] ; i ++){
    double sum = 0;
    NSString *temp = [[results objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"category"];
    for( int j = 0; j< [results count] ; j ++){
        if([temp isEqualToString:[[results objectAtIndex:j]valueForKey:@"category"]]){
            sum = sum + [[[results objectAtIndex:j]valueForKey:@"amount"]doubleValue];
        }
    }
NSLog(@"%f",sum);
NSLog(@"%f",temp);

    }
}
```

Comment: what do u want, u do not want to allow to store the duplicate values in core data? @Sekhar

Comment: I want to store them. But While retrieving or after retrieving i want to sum the amount of all the duplicated categories and show the top 5 expensive categories.

Comment: see my answer once, may be it may help u

Answer (score 0):

what you want is a counted set. heres the docs:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html
Basically, you just put in all the objects you have, then afterwards ask for the count of an object. The counted set will return the amount of times a specific item is in the set. just make sure you use `-countForObject`instead of `-count`.
Have fun

Comment: I dont want the count.I want to sum the duplicates.

Comment: If you have the number of occurences of an object you should easily be able to calculate the sum of the duplicates by using the value of the object and the `-countForObject:` method. (value*count=sum)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the resulting sum into an array by ascending or descending orders. From that array, you can show the top 5 sum from their indices.

Than You

Comment: When the sum is shuffled while sorting.how to get the corresponding category name after it is shuffled?

Answer (score 0):

When u get the values from the core data you can validate the duplicate  values by using

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"amount=%d",previousValueotNot];
```

then below add this code

```
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error;
    NSArray *tempResults = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSLog(@"temparray coun is %d",[tempResults count]);
if ([tempResults count] > 0)
    {

       //sum here the duplicates.
       //sample code is 


NSArray *tempResults = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSMutableArray *tempBudsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for ( Favorite *fav in tempResults) 
    {
      //.. Here u get the values from the core data and sum here  ,then store all the values, later u can put in ascending order
    }


 }
```